# buildSrc: Could not get unknown property for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, android, gradle, buildsrc

I am trying to reorganize this [Android (Java based) library](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/SnackEngage) to use the [*buildSrc*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html) folder to define all versions and dependencies as described in this [article](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/using-buildsrc-custom-logic-gradle-builds).

I already set this successfully up for several times for Kotlin bases projects. This time the project is **pure Java**.

In the `buildSrc` folder I created the following `buildSrc/src/main/java/org/ligi/snackengage/Dependencies.java` file:

```
package org.ligi.snackengage;

public class Dependencies {

    public static class Android { /* ... */ }

    public static class GradlePlugins {
        public static final String ANDROID = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3";
        // ...
    }

    public static class Libs { /* ... */ }

}
```

Then I refer to the definitions in the project root `build.gradle` among others:

```
import org.ligi.snackengage.Dependencies.GradlePlugins

apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath GradlePlugins.ANDROID
        classpath GradlePlugins.MAVEN
        classpath GradlePlugins.VERSIONS
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is the [work in progress branch](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/SnackEngage/tree/project-setup-buildsrc). When I build the project then the following error occurs:

```bash
* Where:
Build file 'SnackEngage/build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SnackEngage'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GradlePlugins' for object of type
  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here is the [build log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/johnjohndoe/snackengage/project-setup-buildsrc-78fdd4d9c7-1/build.log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `GradlePlugins` class as an inner static class of `Dependencies`, so you need to use `Dependencies.GradlePlugins` to access it from your build script.

Change your dependencies block as follows:

```
import org.ligi.snackengage.Dependencies // do not import org.ligi.snackengage.Dependencies.GradlePlugins
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath Dependencies.GradlePlugins.ANDROID
        classpath Dependencies.GradlePlugins.MAVEN
        classpath Dependencies.GradlePlugins.VERSIONS
    }
}
```

**EDIT**  you could also use a static import, as follows:

```
import static org.ligi.snackengage.Dependencies.*
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath GradlePlugins.ANDROID
        classpath GradlePlugins.MAVEN
        classpath GradlePlugins.VERSIONS
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great, see [PR #45](https://github.com/ligi/SnackEngage/pull/45).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variable `GradlePlugins` with `def` (in Gradle) or `public class GradlePlugins` (in Java), before attempting to access it. Kotlin `class GradlePlugins` should also work.

```
dependencies {
    classpath GradlePlugins.ANDROID
    classpath GradlePlugins.MAVEN
    classpath GradlePlugins.VERSIONS
}
```

And I think the `buildSrc` directory belongs into the module directory, as the Gradle manual shows.

Comment: I am not sure what you want me to change. Please have a look at the code snippets or the original source code which I linked. Please note that the project is pure Java not Kotlin.